# Groupwise Max With Filter Optimisation

Tags: mysql, sql, groupwise-maximum

I'm trying here to get rid of subquery in my groupwise max query that gives me unwanted `using temporary`

---

### Schema

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rates` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `currency_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rate` double NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `date_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `my` (`currency_id`,`date_time`),
  KEY `currency` (`currency_id`),
  KEY `date` (`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

---

### The problem

I want the row with latest `date_time` for `the max(date) as date1` and the row with the latest `date_time` for `date2 < date1` for each `currency_id`.

Simply speaking: the latest currency rate for today and the latest one the day before for each currency.

---

This is the solution I came up with based on technique **Top-N in each Group** described here: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max#top_n_in_each_group

```
SELECT
        `id`, `currency_id`, `rate`, `date`, `date_time`, `n`
    FROM
      ( SELECT  @prev := '', @n := 0 ) init
    JOIN
      ( SELECT  @n := if(`currency_id` != @prev, 1, @n + 1) AS n,
                @prev := `currency_id`,
                `id`, `currency_id`, `rate`, `date`, `date_time`
            FROM
            ( SELECT *
              FROM
                ( SELECT *
                   FROM
                     `rates`
                   ORDER BY
                     `date_time` DESC ) v
              GROUP BY
                `currency_id`, `date` ) v
            ORDER BY
                `currency_id`   ASC,
                `date_time` DESC
      ) x
    WHERE  n <= 2;
```

---

Fiddle with test data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/54229/8

Alas, the subquery in `FROM` state produces temp table... I'm wondering, is it even possible to avoid temp tables on advanced groupwise max problems?

---

### EDIT

Ok I think I got something here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/54229/55

```
SELECT
        `id`, `currency_id`, `rate`, `date`, `date_time`
    FROM
      ( SELECT  @prev := '', @prev_date := '', @n := 0, @m := 0 ) init
    JOIN
      ( SELECT  @n := if(`prev` != @prev, 1, @n + if(`date` = @prev_date, 0, 1)) AS n,
                @m := if(`date` != @prev_date, 1, @m + 1) AS m,
                @prev := `prev`,
                @prev_date := `date`,
                `id`, `currency_id`, `rate`, `date`, `date_time`, `prev`
            FROM  (SELECT *, `currency_id` as `prev` FROM `rates`) v
            ORDER BY
                `prev`   ASC,
                `date_time` DESC
      ) x
    WHERE  n <= 2 AND m = 1;
```

---

### EDIT 2

Finally, my solution: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/54229/59

```
SELECT
        v.`id`, v.`currency_id`, v.`rate`, v2.`rate` as `rate_prev`, v.`rate` - v2.`rate` as `change`, v.`date`, v2.`date` as `date_prev`, v.`date_time`, v2.`date_time` as `date_time_prev`
    FROM
      ( SELECT  @group_by := '', @group_by_date := '', @n := 0, @m := 0 ) init
    JOIN
      ( SELECT  *, 
                @m := if(`date` != @group_by_date, 1, 0) AS `m`,
                @n := if(`group_by` != @group_by, 1, @n + @m) AS `n`,
                @group_by := `group_by`,
                @group_by_date := `date`
            FROM  (SELECT *, `currency_id` as `group_by` FROM `rates` ORDER BY `currency_id`, `date` DESC, `date_time` DESC) v
      ) v ON v.n = 1 AND v.m = 1
    LEFT JOIN
      ( SELECT  *, 
                @m := if(`date` != @group_by_date, 1, 0) AS `m`,
                @n := if(`group_by` != @group_by, 1, @n + @m) AS `n`,
                @group_by := `group_by`,
                @group_by_date := `date`
            FROM  (SELECT *, `currency_id` as `group_by` FROM `rates` ORDER BY `currency_id`, `date` DESC, `date_time` DESC) v
      ) v2 ON v.currency_id = v2.currency_id AND v2.n = 2 AND v2.m = 1
```

`O(n)` performance and no temporary tables. I also joined result to itself to get rate changes in single rows.

Comment: Your query is simply wrong, using a MySQL (mis)feature that the documentation explicitly warns against using.  You should explain what you want to accomplish and your desired results.  Your data structure seems quite confusing, with both `date` and a `datetime` columns.

Comment: Explain... But I did, didn't I? Under the _The problem:_
As for `date` and `date_time` - had to use both to avoid calling `date(date_time)`

Comment: You may want to look at solving this in a procedural fashion. You may be able to accomplish it in SQL, but it will either involve many passes over the data or as @GordonLinoff stated, features that can cause indeterminate results.